# Is it meaningful for a Bayesian to look at the point estimation of posterior density?

Tags: r, bayesian, posterior, hierarchical-bayesian, jags

I understand Bayesian look at the quantile. But is it useful to look at the posterior mean and posterior median?

How to explain it in the plain English?

Comment: You have to consider Bayesian decision theory, ie the addition of a loss function to the Bayesian framework.

Comment: When talking about a distribution, we often use summary statistics, such as mean, median, sd, ... In Bayesian, after observing the data, each parameter has a posterior distribution. From this distribution, any summary has prefix posterior. Therefore, we have terms "posterior mean", ...

Comment: To know if something is meaningful, we must know what you want to do, your goal. You didn't tell us!